# How do I redirect all calls on one port to the same URL on another port with apache?

Tags: node.js, apache, sails.js

I'm hosting a sails.js application on the default port 1337. I have an apache serving as its proxy on port 8080:

```
[root@ip-192-168-0-XX conf.d]# cat nodetest.conf
Listen 8080

<VirtualHost 192.168.0.XX:8080>
    Options -Indexes
    ProxyRequests on
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:1337/
</VirtualHost>
```

The Sails application has an API. So for instance, if I want to post a message, I enter this into my browser:

```
http://localhost:1337/Message/postMessage
```

I want that to happen when I enter the same address on port 8080.

```
http://localhost:8080/Message/postMessage
```

I am brand new to this Apache stuff, so I don't even know what the thing I want to do right now is called? Reverse Proxy? Regular Proxy? Redirects? I just don't know.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I guess you would really only need to do this if you have Apache hosting other sites on the same server.

If you have no intention of running other sites on the same server with Apache, you can always just hit the Sails server directly at port 80 or 8080 by changing the port in your sails application in the config/local.js file.

Change

```
 // port: process.env.PORT || 1337,
```

To

```
 port: process.env.PORT || 80,
```

For other applications, like load balancing or basic proxying, I think nginx would be a far better solution.

The standard configuration for using Apache as a proxy for Sails would be something like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com

    ProxyRequests off

    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    <Location />
        ProxyPass http://localhost:1337/
        ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:1337/
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't actually change the behavior of anything for me. I'm still hitting 404 pages on 8080.
The reason I'm doing this is because I have a webgate on this system. I want to be able to do development and testing both with and without webgate-based authentication. Ideally, I want to be able to hit the sails server directly on port 1337 and go through the webgate to the sails server on port 8080

Comment: I don't think your issue is sails related, and what you are describing is perfectly possible. I think you just need more guidance in the Apache area. It could be that you haven't installed the proxy modules for Apache `sudo a2enmod proxy`. For a complete guide on setting up Apache as a proxy for node, see [here](https://www.1and1.com/cloud-community/learn/application/misc/set-up-a-nodejs-app-for-a-website-with-apache-on-ubuntu-1604/)